# [UPDATE]Google Search Python Module

Tags: python

I have a mistake with google search module.
I try to use this module to do multiple requests, but i have a mistake for do each query with the word.

```
alpha = input(colored ("[{}*{}] Enter Path of you're Word : ",'yellow'))
word = open(alpha, 'r') 
Lines = word.readlines() 
query = Lines

try:
    print(colored("[{}+{}] Scan started! Please wait... :)",'red'))
    for gamma in search(query, start=0, tld=beta, num=1000 ,  pause=2): 
        print(colored ('[+] Found > ' ,'yellow')  + (gamma) )
        with open("googleurl.txt","a") as f:
            f.write(gamma + "/" + "\n")        
except:
    print("[{}-{}] Word Liste not found!")
```

I think it's not possible to do multiple query,
Because my dorks is loaded into my python program but query not done. If i change

```
query = "test"
```

I have like 100 requests for the word test. I think i have do a bad things, for do query with the text file.

I'm sorry for my bad English. I'm a beginner with English and also with Python
I hope you can help me

I'm now with this program :

```
alpha = input(colored ("[{}*{}] Wordlist : ",'yellow'))
Word = open(alpha, 'r') 
Lines = Word.readlines() 
query = Lines
beta =  random.choice(TLD)

Word_number = 0 
for line in Lines: 
    Word_number+=1

for query in Lines: 
    print("Nombre de Word: "+str(Word_number))
for i in search(query, start=0, tld=beta, num=1000 ,  pause=2, stop=None):
    print(colored ('[+] Found > ' ,'yellow') +(i))
    URL_number+=1 
    with open("googleurl.txt","a") as f:
        f.write(i + "/" + "\n")
        f.close()
print(colored("[{}+{}] Total Google URL : ",'red') + str(URL_number))
```

And my program answer do this :
He just fount 98 website and stop, and he only check the 1st word

Answer (score 0):

`word.readlines()` returns a **list** of strings, where each item is the next line in the file. This means that `query` is a **list**.

The `search()` function wants `query` to be a **string**, so you'll have to loop through `Lines` to get each individual query:

```py
for query in Lines:
    # perform search with this query
```

Comment: I have update my topic for you see, i think all is good but he didn't find any word ..

Comment: `"[{}-{}] Wordlist not found!"` is printed whenever there is an error. Try Removing the `try except` block and letting it print the error, so you can the find the problem yourself from there

Comment: I have update my topic, now my error is google search not scan my word it's just write my word into the text file.

Really thanks for you're patience

Comment: I successfully create my tool, thanks you a lots of you help. 

Now my error is about : urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests
I think it's because google ban IP

Answer (score -1):

Hey i finally update my code. And i now i have a problem with proxies.
The code is fixed for requests with dorks but i can't find how to add proxy my code is :

```
alpha = input(colored ("[{}*{}] Dorklist : ",'yellow'))
dorks = open(alpha, 'r') 
Lines = dorks.readlines() 
query = Lines
beta =  random.choice(TLD)

ceta = input(colored ("[{}*{}] Proxylist :",'yellow'))
prox = open(ceta, 'r')
Lines2 = prox.readlines()
proxy = Lines2
Dorks_number = 0
Proxy_number = 0 
for line in Lines: 
    Dorks_number+=1
for line in Lines2:
    Proxy_number+=1
print("Nombre de dorks: "+str(Dorks_number))
print("Nombre de Proxy: "+str(Proxy_number))

s = requests.Session(proxies=proxy)
s.cookies.set_policy(BlockAll())

for query in Lines: 
    for i in search(query, start=0, tld=beta, num=1000 ,  pause=2, stop=None):
        print(colored ('[+] Found > ' ,'yellow') +(i))
        URL_number+=1 
        with open("googleurl.txt","a") as f:
            f.write(i + "/" + "\n")
            f.close()    

print(colored("[{}+{}] Total Google URL : ",'red') + str(URL_number))
```

My error :
s = requests.Session(proxies=proxy)
TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'proxies'
Someone have an idea how to done it ?